# help translate this week query from Oracle PL/SQL to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, sql-server-2008, plsql

I have the following query that runs in my Oracle database and I want to have the equivalent for a SQL Server 2008 database:

```
SELECT TRUNC( /* Midnight Sunday */
         NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'SUN') - (7*LEVEL)
       ) AS week_start,
       TRUNC( /* 23:59:59 Saturday */
         NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'SUN') - (7*LEVEL), 'SAT') + 1
       ) - (1/(60*24)) + (59/(60*60*24)) AS week_end
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 /* Get the past 4 weeks */
```

What the query does is get the start of the week and the end of the week for the last 4 weeks.  The number of weeks is arbitrary and should be easily modified in the SQL Server query I want.  It generates data like the following:

```
WEEK_START          WEEK_END
2010-03-07 00:00:00 2010-03-13 23:59:59
2010-02-28 00:00:00 2010-03-06 23:59:59
...
```

The part I'm currently stuck on translating is `CONNECT BY LEVEL` since it seems SQL Server 2008 doesn't have an equivalent.  I would prefer to simply adjust a line like `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4` and have the query generate more or fewer weeks (i.e., I don't want to have to adjust multiple `UNION ALL` statements).

**Edit:** here's what I have so far that gets the beginning and end of the current week:

```
   SELECT week_start,
          DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7, week_start)) AS week_end
   FROM (
          SELECT CAST(
                   CONVERT(
                     VARCHAR(10),
                     DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), GETDATE()),
                     111
                   ) AS DATETIME
                 ) AS week_start
        ) AS week_start_view
```

I don't mind if the query shows the current week start and end date or if it starts at the previous week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified [OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404084/help-translate-this-week-query-from-oracle-pl-sql-to-sql-server-2008/2406484#2406484)' answer because it looked like a good idea, it just had the wrong `week_end` value on each week and also showed future weeks instead of past weeks.  I came up with the following:

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(
           DD, 
           1 - DATEPART(DW, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), starting_date, 111)), 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), starting_date, 111)
         ) AS midnight
  FROM (
         SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -3, GETDATE()) AS starting_date
       ) AS starting_date_view

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATEADD(DD, 7, midnight)
  FROM dates
  WHERE DATEADD(DD, 7, midnight) < GETDATE()
) SELECT midnight AS week_start,
         DATEADD(SS, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7, midnight)) AS week_end
  FROM dates
```

It generates the past 4 weeks:

```
week_start                 week_end
2010-02-14 00:00:00.000    2010-02-20 23:59:59.000
2010-02-21 00:00:00.000    2010-02-27 23:59:59.000
2010-02-28 00:00:00.000    2010-03-06 23:59:59.000
2010-03-07 00:00:00.000    2010-03-13 23:59:59.000
```

This is better than my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404084/help-translate-this-week-query-from-oracle-pl-sql-to-sql-server-2008/2404501#2404501), I think, because it does not rely on another table having a particular number of rows.  The number of weeks generated can be changed by altering only one digit:  the 3 in `SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -3, GETDATE()) AS starting_date`.  The current week is included, and that digit represents how many additional weeks prior to the current week should be shown.

**Iterate over Past Weeks up to Now, Excluding Current Week**

*Update:*  and here's a version that excludes the current week:

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(
           DD,
           1 - DATEPART(DW, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), starting_date, 111)), 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), starting_date, 111)
         ) AS midnight_sunday
  FROM (
         SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -4, GETDATE()) AS starting_date
       ) AS starting_date_view

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATEADD(DD, 7, midnight_sunday)
  FROM dates
  WHERE DATEADD(DD, 7, midnight_sunday) <
        DATEADD(
          DD,
          1 - DATEPART(DW, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)), 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)
        )
) SELECT midnight_sunday AS week_start,
         DATEADD(SS, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7, midnight_sunday)) AS week_end
  FROM dates
```

Its results:

```
week_start                 week_end
2010-02-07 00:00:00.000    2010-02-13 23:59:59.000
2010-02-14 00:00:00.000    2010-02-20 23:59:59.000
2010-02-21 00:00:00.000    2010-02-27 23:59:59.000
2010-02-28 00:00:00.000    2010-03-06 23:59:59.000
```

**Iterate over Past Months up to Now**

I later found a need for a monthly version of this query.  Here is that modification:

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT CAST(
        FLOOR(CAST(starting_date AS DECIMAL(12, 5))) -
        (DAY(starting_date) - 1) AS DATETIME
      ) AS month_start
  FROM (
         SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) AS starting_date
       ) AS starting_date_view

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, month_start)
  FROM dates
  WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, month_start) < GETDATE()
) SELECT month_start,
         DATEADD(SS, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, month_start)) AS month_end
  FROM dates
  ORDER BY month_start DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Use (but don't forget to [vote for Sarah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404084/help-translate-this-week-query-from-oracle-pl-sql-to-sql-server-2008/2420377#2420377)):

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DD, 
                   1 - DATEPART(DW, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), starting_date, 111)), 
                   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), starting_date, 111)
                   ) AS midnight
      FROM (SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -3, GETDATE()) AS starting_date) AS starting_date_view
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DD, 7, midnight)
      FROM dates
     WHERE DATEADD(DD, 7, midnight) < GETDATE()) 
SELECT midnight AS week_start,
       DATEADD(SS, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7, midnight)) AS week_end
  FROM dates
```

Previously:

1. Set the first day of the week to be Sunday with the [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) command:

   ```
   SET DATEFIRST 7
   ```
2. The SQL Server 2005+ equivalent to Oracle's `CONNECT BY LEVEL` is the recursive CTE (ANSI standard btw).  Use:

   ```
   WITH dates AS (
      SELECT DATEADD(DD, 
                     1 - DATEPART(DW, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)), 
                     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)) AS date
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(dd, 7, d.date)
        FROM dates d
       WHERE DATEADD(dd, 7, d.date) <= DATEADD(dd, 4*7, GETDATE()))
   SELECT t.date AS week_start,
          DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7, t.date)) AS week_end
     FROM dates t
   ```

See [this link for explaining how to get the first day of the week](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-first-day-of-week.aspx).  To alter the number of weeks, change the `DATEADD(dd, 4*7, GETDATE())`, where `4` represents the number of weeks you want generated.

Comment: I like that yours is simpler than my solution and that it still has a single point where I can change how many weeks are generated.  I don't know if I'll have access to modify the first day of the week, though.

Comment: Also, I didn't know what CTE was, but a quick Google search found this:  Common Table Expressions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Comment: Wait, just noticed:  what is the 'dates' table in your query?  Is that built into SQL Server 2008, kind of like Oracle's `DUAL` table?

Comment: @Sarah Vessels: SQL Server doesn't need `FROM DUAL` for an equivalent query.  Common Table Expression (CTE) is SQL Server terminology for the `WITH` syntax, supported by Oracle 9i+ - Oracle calls it Subquery Factoring.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: While Oracle has had the `WITH` clause for awhile, Oracle did not support recursion in the `WITH` clause until recently, 11g R2 I believe.

Comment: @Sarah: The dates relation is being created by the `WITH` clause. It is nothing like dual.

Comment: @Shannon:  der, thanks.  That'll teach me to start reading from the middle of a query...

Comment: @OMG Ponies:  just got a chance to run your query.  Your `week_end` is off:  should be `DATEADD(SS, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7, t.date)) AS week_end`.  Also, the query appears to be going into the future (going up into 2011 if I increase the number of weeks) instead of the past.

Comment: @Sarah Vessels: Thanks, corrected.  Reversing the date calculation is easy - add the `-` to the number specified in the `DATEADD` function.  Try the query now.

Comment: @OMG Ponies:  I started working with your query and tried that, but making that a negative number results in only a single week--the current one--being shown.  Also, running your updated query still shows an incorrect end date:  `2010-03-07 00:00:00.000 2010-02-27 23:59:59.000`.  I got your query working, though:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404084/help-translate-this-week-query-from-oracle-pl-sql-to-sql-server-2008/2420377#2420377

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a set:

```
;WITH cte(n) AS
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
)
  SELECT week_start,
          DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7, week_start)) AS week_end
   FROM (
          SELECT CAST(
                   CONVERT(
                     VARCHAR(10),
                     DATEADD(WEEK, -n, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), GETDATE())),
                     111
                   ) AS DATETIME
                 ) AS week_start
                           FROM cte
        ) AS week_start_view;
```

However I will caution you that if your data is datetime and you are going to use these boundaries for query ranges, you should use an open-ended range, e.g. >= 03/07 and < 03/14.  This way you don't miss out any rows that happened between 23:59:59 and midnight; as rare as they may be, they could be important.

Comment: Also if you already have a Numbers table, you could simply replace the CTE and FROM with "FROM dbo.Numbers WHERE Number BETWEEN 1 AND 4"

Comment: I like this.  I bet the `WITH` could be changed to be more like my `level_view` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404084/help-translate-this-week-query-from-oracle-pl-sql-to-sql-server-2008/2404501#2404501) and then I could specify a number instead of doing multiple unions.

Comment: The UNION is pretty simple to throw together when the number of rows is this small, and a Numbers table is much easier than deriving a row number from an existing table and relying on the fact that it will always have enough rows to satisfy your query.  A lot of people are against an auxiliary table (not sure why); personally I think they are very useful.  YMMV.

Comment: I wrote a bit about the numbers table here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/07/bad-habits-to-kick-using-a-loop-to-populate-a-table.aspx and a long time ago here: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with.  It's slightly janky in that it relies on at least one of my tables having rows >= the number of weeks I want to select.  I could adjust it slightly to include the current week.

```
   SELECT week_start,
          DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7, week_start)) AS week_end
   FROM (
          SELECT CAST(
                   CONVERT(
                     VARCHAR(10),
                     DATEADD(
                       DAY,
                       1-DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()),
                       DATEADD(DAY, -7*level, GETDATE())
                     ),
                     111
                   ) AS DATETIME
                 ) AS week_start
          FROM (
                 SELECT level
                 FROM (
                        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RAND()) AS level
                        FROM my_table_with_at_least_21_rows
                      ) AS all_rows_view
                 WHERE level <= 21
               ) AS level_view
        ) AS week_start_view
```

This gets the past 21 weeks, starting at last week.  Here's sample data:

```
week_start                  week_end
2010-02-28 00:00:00.000     2010-03-06 23:59:59.000
2010-02-21 00:00:00.000     2010-02-27 23:59:59.000
2010-02-14 00:00:00.000     2010-02-20 23:59:59.000
2010-02-07 00:00:00.000     2010-02-13 23:59:59.000
...
```

Comment: 1) how did "4" become "21" in level comparison?  2) have a look at the master..spt_values table

Comment: I clarified my question later to say that I wanted to be able to adjust the number of weeks generated.  Sorry, I should also have phrased my question to say that the number of weeks generated is arbitrary and should be easily modified.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, weeks.week * -7, week_start) AS week_start,
       DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, (weeks.week-1) * -7, week_start)) AS week_end
FROM (
      SELECT CAST(
               CONVERT(
                 VARCHAR(10),
                 DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), GETDATE()),
                 111
               ) AS DATETIME
             ) AS week_start
     ) AS week_start_view,
     ( SELECT 0 AS week UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) AS weeks
```